# loading data into session only once

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page where I'm loading some data into the session.

I put the lines of code that call my queries in the **Page_Init event of the master page**, inside an if statement

`if (!Page.IsPostBack){ load data from queries into the session` }

Is this what I need for all the session data to be loaded only once per session. What about call backs? Do I also need to check to avoid a reload of session data on call backs? Any other condition I need to check to avoid unnecessary reloads of session data? I'm looking to run the queries inside the condition statement only once.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you just posted won't guarantee that will be called **once per session**. In fact, every time your **ASPX** page is invoked with a `GET` command, the data will be loaded.

If you want data to be loaded just once by HTTP session (I am assuming by **session** you mean HTTP session) then try [`Session_OnStart` event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx).

Comment: in what file does the Session_OnStart go? In the master page code behind or somewhere else?

Comment: Nevermind, got it: go to the root, right click, Add Item, global application file and the code is generated. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the session variable is null. If it is null then load the data.  If it is not null then do nothing.

As Pablo Santa Cruz suggests, the best place to load the session variable is in the Sessio_OnStart event handler but a quick and dirty way is to simply check for the sessions existence in the Page_Init event.